# setTimeout/Interval - infinity loop

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I don't know how to do infinity loop by using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` which takes one second all the time. In this code, first-second and second-third change is correct (1 second) but between third and first it takes around 2 seconds. Can you please help me?

```
const n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
const n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
const n3 = document.getElementById("n3");

let num = 0;

const changeSlide = () => {
    num++;
    if (num > 3) num = 0;
    if (num == 0) {
        n1.style.display = "flex";
        n2.style.display = "none";
        n3.style.display = "none";
    } else if (num == 1) {
        n1.style.display = "none";
        n2.style.display = "flex";
        n3.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        n1.style.display = "none";
        n2.style.display = "none";
        n3.style.display = "flex";
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        changeSlide();
    }, 1000);
};

window.onload = () => {
    changeSlide();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your third condition is resolving to `true` twice. You are checking if the number is greater than 3, but you have conditionals for 0, 1, and everything else. Thus your `else` block is true when the number is 2 AND when the number is 3. Thus the last part executes twice. To fix this, change `if (num > 3) num = 0;` to `if (num >= 3) num = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

A piece of advice from me. 
Remove this part:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    changeSlide();
}, 1000);
```

from `changeSlide` method.
Move it to the `window.onload` which will look like:

```
window.onload = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
         changeSlide();
    }, 1000);
};
```

In that way, when the page is loaded, the scheduled task (i.e `changeSlide()`) will be called every second.
That is, `window.onload` will initiate the process that will be called every second.

This seems to be more natural way of creating repetitive code invocation.